# Lost all my ID documents and money. How to fly home from Spain to Slovakia?

Tags: schengen, spain, ryanair, lost-documents, slovakia

I live in Slovakia and went to Spain for few months, where I lost my wallet with all the documents inside. I got here with RyanAir and would like to go back soon. I only have police report for losing ID and photo copies of my documents. I am absolutely broke, means that I really have only money for going back, also that only barely.. I am in Valencia and it would cost over 100 euro to go to Madrid embassy to get travel document. That is even more than flight back home. Can you please help me, what are my options or which are the best ones?

Comment: Can hitchhiking be an option? I mean can he search for a lift to Madrid ?

Comment: You can go from Valencia to Madrid by bus by as little as 27€, see this search in [Go Euro](https://www.goeuro.com/buses_from_valencia_to_madrid)

Comment: Did you have any debit or credit cards? Some can provide emergency replacements or emergency funds while abroad. You may also try to get someone back home to send you some money via Western Union, though you would need to check they can give you the money without ID.

Comment: Slovakia has a Consulate General in Barcelona, which is a bit closer and may also be able to help you: https://www.mzv.sk/web/madrid-en/honorary-consulates?p_p_id=zudatadisplayhk_WAR_MzvZuZobrPortlety&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_zudatadisplayhk_WAR_MzvZuZobrPortlety_id=31291

Comment: rome2rio.com searches through several alternatives to find connections between two places: https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Valencia-Spain/Madrid I would inform if you can travel with documents stating that you lost your ID (some transport companies do not allow this, especially if you cross borders).

Comment: A lesson; always carry cash (cards, passport, id, driving license) in multiple places apart your wallet; unless you are [Milan from Slovakia in Milan](https://pics.me.me/milan-italy-milan-slovakia-3393417.png). I wonder what the embassy people told you; and if they provided you with some emergency funds...

Answer (score 27):

If you haven't called the [Embassy of Slovakia in Madrid](https://www.mzv.sk/web/madrid-en) yet, call them for advice.  Going to get an emergency travel document from them is still probably your best option.  Avanzabus.com currently sells tickets from Valencia to Madrid for €30.

Comment: I called and they told me that there is a possibility for me to find an agency that will let me go back home without necessity to go to Madrid and I will be able to get my new ID at home, so I keep trying to find a way, thanks for the tip with avanzabus! I will check it

Answer (score 8):

Sorry about your terrible situation.

I don't think you will be able to fly without getting to Madrid embassy to sort out travel documents.

It won't be a great journey, but have you considered the coach?  I have found [Eurolines](https://www.eurolines.eu) connections from Valencia to Bratislava for €127.

```
02/06 15:30 Valencia - Paris 03/06 12:00
03/06 15:00 Paris - Bratislava 04/06 09:15
```

Comment: Some coach lines insist on seeing ID too for international Schengen journeys. OPs best bet would be some something like BlaBlaCar.

Comment: I havent heard about coaches, what is that? And Blablacar yeah someone mentioned that to me, how does it work and what is the price? Thanks you are amazing with your help

Comment: @Sairus, a coach is a long-distance bus.

Comment: @Sairus.  Blablacar is car sharing, where people offer a lift in a car for a journey they were going to do anyway.  In exchange you then pay a contribution towards fuel costs.  You can search for journeys on their website, but it might take a while to connect all the way to Slovakia.

Comment: I love you for helping me with so many tips! ^_^

Comment: Is it fine to travel through borders with BlaBlaCar with ID copies and police report? I also have a Certificate of Personal Trainer in fitness haha

Comment: As you are travelling through Schengen then you shouldn't need papers at all.  Even if you were stopped then I don't think you would have a problem with the copies.

Comment: @JonathanReez Blablacar actually [asks](https://www.blablacar.co.uk/faq/question/what-documents-do-i-need-when-travelling-abroad)  the drivers to check for ID of all passengers before the trip starts. It doesn't always happens in practice, but the OP would be still breaking the rules by travelling by car without proper ID.

Comment: Blablacar may be more relevant as a potentially cheaper way to get to Madrid and visit the consulate. As a way of getting from Valencia to Slovakia it might not be so cheap: any reasonably sensible route would go through Catalonia, which has a lot of expensive toll roads, and a Blablacar driver for that section of the journey would likely take that into account when setting their price.

Answer (score 7):

Ahoj! :) You have several options:

1) Get money from your family real quick. This can be done using Western Union, you get the money they send you immediatelly.

2) Get to Madrid by bus, blablacar or hitchhiking. Several years ago I was hitchiking in Spain with my ex-gf and it was really going well. Hitchhiking alone takes more time but works - and you get there free of charge.

3) To get to Slovakia, consider sharing a car - you can use http://www.spolujizda.cz/ or https://www.blablacar.cz/ . We once used JizdoMat car-sharing service (now bought by blablacar), and it was the cheapest way to get to Prague (from France), appart from hitchhiking. It took less than 24 hours (from Nimes).

4) As for the borders question, I crossed several times and there are absolutely no checks on the borders in question. All countries are part of Schengen. You almost don't even notice you are crossing a border. Not sure about Swiss, but you don't need to pass through it. So you won't need your documents there, but there might be occasional police checks on the road. Your police report would probably suffice there.

Comment: So, I checked BlaBlaCar and I found out a guy who is actually from czech republic so we live very close to each other and he is traveling from Barcelona to Prague by car, so I think I would choose this option, what means that I will go by car with police report and copies of ID from Barcelona to Prague, thanks a lot for your help and if you are so amazing, could you please confirm that this is of the best ideas to return home with getting any documents in my country after I get there? Gracias!

Comment: @Sairus yes, I think it's the best idea! Don't loose your time in maňana country :-D It will be much easier and cheaper to do all this at home. I think your solution rocks and luck is with you. Do videnia!

Answer (score 5):

- Find a bus to Madrid, first bus in the morning. The trains will ask you for an ID, don't know if photocopies suffice. And it's also more expensive.
- Contact someone back home, ask them to buy you the bus ticket with a debit card
- go to embassy and get travel docs
- contact someone back home again. But now ask them to send you money through Western Union. It's automatic (like 5-10 min.)
- Now, you have money and ID
- Take last bus back if you have to. You can also ask people to buy your plane ticket.

  Note:
- make sure the embassy can help you right away. Call them, do not just check their web-page.
- they could also send you money through Paypal

Comment: "contact someone back home again. But now ask them to send you money through Western Union. It's automatic (like 5-10 min.)". Phone rather than email - an email "please help, I've lost all my documents and cash.  Send me money by Western Union" is a classic scam.

Comment: You won't be asked for an ID to travel by train if you buy the ticket in person at the station: only if you buy it online or in a travel agency. [Reference](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/info/billeteidentificativo.html).

Comment: @makhdumi: that's why he goes 1st to the consulate.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: yes, but the idea is to have your ticket bought from afar. I don't know how much money the OP has in the pocket, but trains are considerably more expensive than buses in Spain.

Comment: Perhaps you could make that clearer? E.g. add "*If someone buys the ticket online for it*" before the sentence about ID. (PS FWIW the last time I got the AVE from Valencia to Madrid I bought the tickets online and they didn't check my ID; but now that I understand why you mention it I agree that it's worth mentioning: better to be safe than sorry).